# Is there any tool to visualize the bitcoin transaction graphs?

Tags: privacy

I want to visualize the bitcoin transaction graph linked to addresses that could potentially link my addresses and to better chose which coins I would use for which payment to prevent [loosing privacy](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Privacy#Blockchain_attacks_on_privacy). Is there any tool that could help me build that graph and visualize the clusters that could be formed?

Answer (score 3):

Check out KYCP.org. They have good visual and written explanations of heuristics used by chain analysis companies, such as common-input, round numbers and change outputs, and address reuse.

OXT.me is also a good website. I think they're related in some way, but provide slightly different visualizations and heuristics.

Comment: "I think they're related in some way" => Yep, same authors :)